# WooCommerce endpoints not working

Tags: android, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to access the products in my woocommerce inventory. It is working fine. But if I try to access the list of products based on a category , it gives me the same result i.e. it is not considering the category endpoint.

When I use http://dev.appilyever.com/newsite/wc-api/v3/products, I get the list of products. But when I use http://dev.appilyever.com/newsite/wc-api/v3/products?categories=tops I get the same set of results. Ideally it should send me the products with category= tops. Please tell me where am I going wrong.

Comment: I am referring https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out how to filter :

For filtering we have to send the request in the below format

Instead of http:/dev.appilyever.com/newsite/wc-api/v3/products?categories=tops

Use

http://dev.appilyever.com/newsite/wc-api/v3/products?filter[category]=tops

As per the documentation at https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3.html#version

"v3 deprecated the product/sku/ endpoint (because a SKU can be generated with any character and there is a filter, filter[sku], that covers this use case)."

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is not filter for that as stated in the issue [here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/5453) and [here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/6241)

What I did was to do the filtering of products on the app side though it is not very effective.